# How does VS Code treat file locality when you open a folder?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a project where I'm referencing a file in the same folder as my `palindromes.py` file:

```
import load_dictionary

word_list = load_dictionary.load('words.txt')

pali_list = []

for word in word_list:
    if len(word) > 1 and word[:] == word [::-1]:
        pali_list.append(word)

print(f'\nNumber of palindromes found = {len(pali_list)}')

print(*pali_list, sep='\n')
```

When I open VS Code in that folder the code runs properly:

[image: VS Code in the folder]

However if I open VS Code higher up the directory tree then navigate down I get 'file not found' unless I use the full path:

[image: higher up the tree]

Is this how it's supposed to work? I would have thought that (as long as I was in the correct folder in the tree structure) Python would know to run *in that folder*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you execute your code, your current working directory will be set to the top of your workspace, so Python thinks you're working from `learning-python` and not `02_finding_palingram_spells`. If you're using Python 3, you can do:

```py
import os
import pathlib

word_path = pathlib.Path(__spec__.origin).parent / "words.txt"
word_list = load_dictionary.load(os.fspath(word_path))
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with "." at the beggining. For example:

```
word_list = load_dictionary.load('./02_finding_palingram_spells/words.txt')
```